# Trying to include ID column in Grouped SQL SELECT statement in order to drill down in web page

Tags: sql, .net, webmatrix

I know there has been a lot of discussion around this subject but I cannot find anything that points me in the direction of a definitive answer.

I have the below sql statement within a .net page in Webmatrix:

```
    SELECT vehicle, vehicleDescription, count(vehicleDescription) AS 'Total' 
FROM vehicles 
WHERE (branchRequirement = 'Manchester') 
AND (deliveryBranch = 'Manchester' OR deliveryBranch IS NULL) 
AND (dateDeliveredToBranch > GETDATE() OR dateDeliveredToBranch IS NULL) 
AND (vgc LIKE 'B_') GROUP BY vehicle,vehicleDescription
```

The output is obviously GROUPED data for the chosen conditions.

What I am trying to do is provide a link in my Webgrid on the .net page which allows the user to open a child page with details of the GROUPED vehicles.

Where I'm getting stuck is I cannot include the vehicleID in the GROUP BY because they are obviously all UNIQUE.

Has anybody come across this or something similar with any degree of success as I am pulling my hair out with it which I can ill afford to do!

Thanks

M

Comment: Can you provide a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) and an expected output?

Comment: There isn't enough detail here to answer your question *(we need to know the schema at least)*, but it sounds as though your relation database model doesn't differentiate between an *abstract* Vehicle and an *instance* of a vehicle.  Much like the difference between a *Class* and an *Object*.  If you have a column such as `vehicleTypeID` and another column such as `Vehicle` then you could group by the first and count the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across similar issues and the solution I came up with was to use the information you already have. When the user clicks on the link, you know the vehicle and the vehicleDescription that the user wants to see. You should not need the vehicleId because you are not going to have one unique result. If they click on a vehicle that has a count of 3, the child page should have details about all 3 results.

In order to find the 3 results the user would want to see, you can alter your existing query and use it for the child page. The altered query should take the vehicle and vehicleDesciption as parameters.

```
SELECT *
FROM vehicles 
WHERE (branchRequirement = 'Manchester') 
AND (deliveryBranch = 'Manchester' OR deliveryBranch IS NULL) 
AND (dateDeliveredToBranch > GETDATE() OR dateDeliveredToBranch IS NULL) 
AND (vgc LIKE 'B_')
AND vehicle = @vehicle
AND vehicleDesciption = @vehicleDescription
```

Pass the parameters in .Net and you should end up with the same data that you summed in your last query, since this query is essentially the same.